# fontawesome 6.2 animations are not working at all

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to get a spinner icon to spin with no success. I have downloaded the latest font awesome and created a very basic html file to try and eliminate any variables to make it work.

Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="C:/Users/<my-user-name>/Downloads/fontawesome-free-6.2.0-web/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code renders the icon but the animation doesn't work.

The only thing I have noticed is that when I inspect the icon element in chrome and look at the style details for .fa-spin, it shows a style called animation-timing-function: var(--fa-animation-timing, linear); but when I hover over that style, text appears stating "--fa-animation-timing is not defined".

As far as I can tell from the [fontawesome host yourself instructions](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts) I have included everything I need. I didn't delete any files from the extracted free font awesome download. I also tried the alternative option to referencing all.css, which involves referencing fontawesome.css, brands.css and solid.css.

What am I missing here?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I just discovered this issue today, as well. Even on their website (https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/style/animate), it doesn't work. So far, it seems to be limited to Windows. Tried it with Firefox and different Chromium variants. Works on iOS and OSX, tho.

Comment: 1 year later and this is still happening. Chrome on Windows. Has this project been abandoned?

Answer (score 6):

We just ran into this issue and found the potential reason.

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/troubleshoot/

Points to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion#user_preferences

And when we toggled "Show animations in Windows." The animations started working again.

Comment: This also worked on Chrome 112 and macOS 13.